# git stash and branch previous working version?

Tags: git

I created a `branch A`, made some changes and as "everything was ok" I `committed`.
Then I continued working in A, but everything has become quite messy, however I have a good intuition in that mess (maybe it's not lol).

Is there a form to `stash` the mess, create a new `branch B` starting from the "everything was ok" `in branch A` and continue working in `branch B`? I'm thinking in coming back to the mess in `branch A` later and hopefully merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new branch, there's no need to stash. You can create a new branch starting from the latest good commit.
While in `branch A`, get the hash of the latest good commit, by using `git log`. Then run:

```
git checkout <branchA_hash> -b branchB
```

This will create a new branch called `branchB`, updated at that commit you've chosen.

In any moment you can then come back to your *messy* branch A by just checking it out again.

Comment: He doesn't want branchA_hash, he wants branchA_hash~X, going back to the "everything was ok" point previously seen on branchA

Comment: that's exactly what I meant. `branchA_hash` is not the pointer to HEAD, but the hash of the latest good commit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly...

```
#Stash those changes
git stash
#Create a new branch - all changes are now stashed
git checkout -b branchB
#Restore stashed changes
git stash pop
#Commit "mess" on branch B
git commit -a -m "what a terrible mess..."
#Change to branch A
git checkout branchA
```

As you said, later on a merge would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use

```
git checkout <A_Branch> -b Bbranch
```